# jcarousellite stop on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousellite

hi 
i have a page with jcarousellite showing some images and scrolling auto after every 5 seconds i want to stop the scroll when i click on any image in carousel

here is what i am trying to do

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.slider_images').jCarouselLite({
        btnNext: "#next",
        btnPrev: "#prev",
        auto:  3000         
    }); 

    $(".slider_images img").click(function(){


        $('.slider_images').jCarouselLite({
            btnNext: "#next",
            btnPrev: "#prev",
            scroll: false       
        }); 


    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am so sorry for very late response. My problem was solved. We can achieve stop on click property very easily by changing pauseOnHover option of jcarousellite. If you see the implementation of pauseOnHover, its something like this:

```
o.pauseOnHover ? ul.hover(function (){ paused == 1 }, function (){paused=0}) : "";
```

we can achieve stop on click by changing ul.hover to ul.click

```
o.pauseOnHover ? ul.click(function (){ paused == 1 }, function (){paused=0}) : "";
```

Have a Nice Day.

Answer (score 0):

i read the code for a while and found out that the auto scrolling is implemented by using a `setTimeout`:

```
if(o.auto)
    setInterval(function() {
        go(curr+o.scroll);
    }, o.auto+o.speed);
```

If you use `jCarouselLite` a second time it won't stop the `setTimeout`. To stop a `setTimout` you have to invoke `window.clearTimeout`:

```
var timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function(){...}, 100);

window.clearTimeout(timeoutId);
```

This is impossible since the code of jcarousel didn't provide you with these `timeoutId`. You can talk to the developer or modify the code on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to disagree with [scheffield](https://stackoverflow.com/users/504356/scheffield) and/or find a work around using this plug-in, but I have to agree with him - it would take a rewriting of the source to do what you wanted. Alternatively, you may want to consider [jquery cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html). It has 'pause' and 'stop' methods already there.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the top of the file

```
var timers = new Array();
```

change

```
setInterval(function(){go(curr+o.scroll)},o.auto+o.speed)
```

to

```
timers.push(new Array( this.className, setInterval(function(){go(curr+o.scroll)},o.auto+o.speed)));
```

to stop a scroll

```
var classToStop = ".TestClass"; 

for(var i=0; i < timers.length; i++)
{
    if("."+timers[i][0] == uploadifyClass)
    window.clearInterval(timers[i][1])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will stop all carousels auto progression on the page. I am killing everything that is using a timeout here. This worked for me:

```
$(".slider_images img").click(function(){
    var x = setTimeout("");
    for (var i = 0 ; i < x ; i++)
    clearTimeout(i);
}
```

Comment: This may work in most browser, however it's using undefined behavior. The specification for the returned number of `setTimeout` only specifies that it must be a number, it doesn't require it to be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".mycarousel").trigger('stopCarousel');
```

If you're using the newest jcarousel https://github.com/kswedberg/jquery-carousel-lite/

This event isn't in their documentation for some reason although pauseCarousel is.